# Reverse ColorFunction or ColorData

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

please excuse my bad English, I'm not a native speaker.

This should be fairly simple: **Is there a simple way to "reverse" ColorFunction or ColorData?**

Let me explain what I mean. Let's say, we have the following plot:

```
Plot[x, {x, 1, 10}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

As you can see, the upper part of the plot is colored red, the lower part is colored blue/purple. How do I reverse that? So that the upper part is purple, the lower part red.

Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

---

If you're curious why I ask that: I have made this plot showing the number of molecules of three biological substances over time when metabolized by the body.

[image: Image of two plots]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reverse the colours you could try `1-#` instead of just `#` in a pure function passed to `ColorFunction`. To change how the line segments are coloured, include an exponent as follows.

```
Manipulate[
   Plot[E^{-x, -1.2 x, -2.4 x}, {x, 0, 5},
      ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow", (1 - #)^e] &),
      PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 450,
      FrameLabel -> {"Zeit in Minuten", "Anzahl der Wirkstoffmoleküle"}],
   {{e, 1.0, "Exponent"}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: exponential decay]

Answer (score 17):

This may be a shorter solution.

```
Plot[x, {x, 1, 10}, ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", "Reverse"}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have found one possible solution… :)

```
Plot[x, {x, 1, 10}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Reverse@ColorData["Rainbow"][y]]]
```

Is there a better way?